# Cannot get value of radio button in jquery: 'Syntax error, unrecognized expression'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I have 2 radio buttons in html. I want to get the 'value' of whichever radio button is checked.

```
<input type="radio" name='match' value='all' checked>Match <b>All</b> Tags</input>
<input type="radio" name='match' value='any'>Match <b>Any</b> Tags</input>
```

Using jquery, I have tried all of the following:

```
var matchAll = $("input[type='radio']:checked").val();
var matchAll = $("input[type='radio'][name='match']:checked").val();
var matchAll = $("input:radio[name='match']:checked").val();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XG4fD/

And they each give roughly the same error:

**Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[type=='radio']:checked**

**Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[type=='radio'][name=='match']:checked**

**Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input:radio[name=='match']:checked**

Comment: jQuery working ok otherwise?

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle of this issue? From the errors, it looks like the problem is the `==`.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LbmC4/ here is the fiddle, and its working fine!

Comment: The error messages do not fit your code! In the error `==` is used, while your code uses `=`!

Comment: Yes, jQuery is working perfectly otherwise... This error pops up in an internet explorer 9 window.

And yes, I know the error doesn't match the code... but that is what the dialog window in IE9 shows.

Comment: Input type radio has't close tag. Incorrect syntax.
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Male

Answer (score 1):

try again with code below:

```
var match = $('input[name=match]:checked').val();
```

or

```
$('input[name=match]:checked').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="taskmaster-task_status_id_edit" aria-required="true">
<label class="radio-inline"><input name="TaskMaster[task_status_id]" value="1" type="radio"> Completed</label>
<label class="radio-inline"><input name="TaskMaster[task_status_id]" value="2" type="radio"> Cancelled</label>
<label class="radio-inline"><input name="TaskMaster[task_status_id]" value="3" type="radio"> Rescheduled</label>
<label class="radio-inline"><input name="TaskMaster[task_status_id]" value="4" type="radio"> Queued</label>
</div>


<script>
 //some condition,you have to put for every value 1,2,3,etc
 $('#taskmaster-task_status_id_edit').find(':radio[name="TaskMaster[task_status_id]"][value="4"]').prop('checked', true);
</script>
```

I am 4 years late but if it helps someone I had a similar problem. 
It can be done using the above method. Remember the name has to be in double quotes or it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var value = "";
$("input[type='radio'][name='match']").each(function(){
  if($(this).is(":checked"))
    value = $(this).val();
});
```

You get the value of the checked one only...

Comment: Unfortunately this code gives me a similar error:
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[type=='radio'][name=='match']

http://imgur.com/9ay6RkA

Answer (score 0):

Using simple javascript:

```
<script>
function val(matchAll)
{
    document.getElementById("op").innerHTML=matchAll;
}
</script>
<input type="radio" id="I1" onclick="val(I1.value);" value="all" />Match All Tags
<input type="radio" id="I2" onclick="val(I2.value);" value="any" />Match Any Tags
<div id="op"></div>
```